# regular expression Python with at least 3 upper cases

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular Expression that Matches a string that mustn't contain digits. The string should have at least 3 upper cases. In addition, the string should contain 6 to 40 chars.

Here is my Approach, but it doesnt work as I expect it to:

```
re.findall("\\n(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})[^0-9]{6,40}:\\n",text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: If you want _at least_ 3 then you should use `{3,}` and not just `{3}`.

Comment: I've already tried this, but unfortunately it doesnt work either.

Comment: @accidias No. That is a *lookahead assertion* requiring that the input contains 3 uppercase letters. There is no need to say that it must have 3 *or more* because  assertions do not actually match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best accomplished with `lookahead assertions` (you were on the right track). These assert what the input must or must not contain at the current scan point without actually consuming (matching) any characters:

```
^(?!\D*\d)(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3}).{6,40}$
```

1. `^` matches the start of the string (superfluous when using `re.match` since this is implied).
2. `(?!\D*\d)` asserts that there is no digits in the input at this point.
3. `(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})` asserts that there are 3 uppercase letters in the input at this point.
4. `.{6,40}` matches any 6 - 40 characters other than newline.
5. `$` matches the end of the string.

The code:

```
import re

strings = [
    'abcDefGdjIj', # OK
    'abcDefdjIj',  # not enough uppercase
    'DGdIj', # too short
    'abcDef7GdjIj' # has a digit
   ]

for string in strings:
    print(string, re.match(r'^(?!\D*\d)(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3}).{6,40}$', string))
```

Prints:

```
abcDefGdjIj <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='abcDefGdjIj'>
abcDefdjIj None
DGdIj None
abcDef7GdjIj None
```

If you are searching for multiple valid matches in a multiline string using `re.findall`, then you should use the following regex with flags `re.MULTILINE`:

```
^(?!.*\d)(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3}).{6,40}$
```

1. `^` matches the start of the string or the start of a line.
2. `(?!.*\d)` asserts that there are no digits in the input but by using `.*` instead of `\D`, it ensures we do not scan past the end of the line.
3. `(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3})` likewise ensure we have 3 uppercase letters in the input before the end of the line.
4. `.{6,40}` matches any 6 - 40 characters other than newline.
5. `$` matches the end of line or the end of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98HviN/2)

The code:

```
import re

strings = """abcDefGdjIj
abcDefdjIj
DGdIj
XYZabcDefGdjIj
abcDef7GdjIj"""

print(re.findall(r'^(?!.*\d)(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3}).{6,40}$', strings, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

Prints:

```
['abcDefGdjIj', 'XYZabcDefGdjIj']
```

Why the two flavors of regular expressions? In the first case where we are just matching a single string and we want to ensure that the input doesn't contain a digit, we could use either `(?!\D*\d)` or the more general `(?!.*\d)`, but the first one is more efficient. We cannot, however, use that for the second, multiline `findall` case because `\D*` can scan across newline boundaries whereas `.*` will not assuming you do not have the `re.DOTALL` flag set.